# dynamicaly adding textboxes to zend_form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I hope that this is a quick question to answer.  I am developing a form using `Zend_Form`, I have a number of `Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Textboxs` to add to this form dynamically.

These are added from rows in the database, e.g.

```
$count = 0;
            //we now loop through the skill types and add them to the form.
            foreach($skillResult as $skill){

                $skillTextBox = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ValidationTextBox('skill-'.$count,
                    array('trim' => true,
                        'NotEmpty' => true,
                        'invalidMessage' => 'This can not be blank'
                    )
                );
                $skillTextBox->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                    ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
                    ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
                    ->removeDecorator('Label');

                //add the element to the form.
                $myForm->addElement($skillTextBox);

                $count++;

            }
```

The form is then displayed in a view script, that I need to extract however.  As I do not know how many 'skill' textboxes exist in the form I am not sure how I can loop through and add them to the view script.  I would normally look at adding them to the viewScript in the following way:

```
<?php foreach($this->element->getElement('skill') as skill) :?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $skill;?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

However I am getting an error message of *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

Am I going about this in a backward way and change my approach to this form or am I missing somthing here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the form in a controller's action function, you can do something like this to tell your view script how many skill text boxes you added..

In controller:

```
$this->view->skillTextBoxCount = $count;
```

In view:

```
// the view is now "this"
$skillCount = $this-skillTextBoxCount;
```

You could also do something like this:

```
$elements = $form->getElements();
foreach($elements as $element) {
   if (strpos($element->getName(), 'skill-') === 0) { // must use === here
      // do something with your element
   }
}
```